# How can i normalize this to BCNF?

Tags: database-normalization

The relation is

```
 Student(StdNo,StdName,appointNo,timing,advisor)
```

and the functional dependancies are:

```
   StdNo->StdName
   StdNo,appointNo->Timing,advisor
   Timing->appointNo
```

By normalising to 2NF I get:

```
   R1(stdNo,appointNo,Timing,advisor)
   R2(stdNo,StdName)
```

I think this is already in 3NF. But I am having trouble reducing to BCNF.

For BCNF, i think the R1 relation violates BCNF as Timing-> appointNo and Timing is not a super key. How can i reduce to BCNF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in considering that the decomposition in `R1`, `R2` is in 3NF but not in BCNF, for the reason you have specified (`timing → appointNo` violates the normal form).

So you should decompose `R2` in `R3(timing, appointNo)` and `R4(StdNo, advisor, timing)`, and the final decomposition is `R1, R3, R4`.

Note that with this decomposition the dependency `StdNo,appointNo → timing,advisor` is not preserved.